# How to remove UIButton selected background color?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton, uikit

I am looking for a solution to this problem that does NOT require using images/PNGs. I am looking for a way to remove the `UIButton`'s blue background color when it's in selected state, and I just cannot find a way to do that without using images. I am basically trying to do something like that in case of a `UITableViewCell`:

```
   cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

Comment: Wow, just tried all of these answers on a custom button and could get none of them to work.

Comment: If you're looking for a solution to this and you're using the button Configuration introduced in iOS 15, see @Mitesh's answer (or search this page for "Configuration").

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Unfortunately I'm away from my test machine at the moment, but there are two things you could try.

First would be to set the following property:

```
button.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
```

Or uncheck "Highlight adjusts image" in Interface Builder.

If that doesn't work like you expect it to, you can deselect the button in the action you tied it to, like so:

```
- (IBAction)yourButtonAction:(id)sender {
    [sender setHighlighted:NO];
}
```

Comment: does it but not in a clean way - when I click, you still see the blue color for a brief moment. I am hoping to find a solution that will eliminate that completely.

Comment: Then why don't you just create your own `UIControl`?  It's not that hard.  Then you can customize it to your heart's content.

Comment: Still Works great, ios:9.3, just `button.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO` is enough.

Comment: I set `tintColor` property of `UIButton` to `clear`  it removed the background blue color when selected

Answer (score 132):

I had this same issue and I resolve it by changing the UIButton type from "System" to "Custom".  The blue background color does not show up in selected state when it is a "Custom" type.

Comment: Simple, but it removes the nice fade on touch. :(

Comment: @KyleClegg just change the Highlighted color and it should fade to that color on touch.

Answer (score 10):

Change the alpha of the tintColor to zero, works if iOS is 5.0 or later

```
UIColor *color = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.0];  
button.tintColor = color;
```

Comment: This makes the button text flicker

Comment: Increases CPU use for blending

Comment: You can just set `button.tintColor = .clear` in Swift 5

Comment: If `tintColor` is clear, then once button's `state` will be set to `selected`, no text will be visible.

Answer (score 10):

Very simple, in `storyBoard`, select your `UIButton` and open `attribute inspector`. Now scroll down to `View` section and change `Tint` property to `Clear Color` or any specific color if u want.

[image]

Comment: I know your answer is correct, but unfortunately after updating the Xcode, this is not working for new version of Xcode 13. Can you explain what does happened with the new Xcode? I want to remove the background color and tint color both, because I have a button on top of big uiview.!

Comment: you need to change button type on XIB file

Answer (score 5):

UIButton also with `custom` type, we can set it in `xcode` as-

[image]

**OR**
By programmatically as-

```
 let customButton = UIButton(type: .custom) 
  customButton.setTitle("this is Button", for: .normal)
  customButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: .normal)
  customButton.frame = CGRect(x: 15, y: 50, width: 300, height: 500)
            self.view.addSubview( customButton)
```

Now there is no more *UIButton's blue background color*

Answer (score 3):

Not a direct answer to OP's question but to remove this colour in a `UIButton` subclass you can do this:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    tintColor = .clear
}
```

Comment: Why would you do this in `layoutSubviews`?

Comment: Good question, where do you suggest?

Comment: Assuming that setting the `tintColor` actually works at all, set it somewhere that typically only gets called once. Perhaps `didMoveToSuperview()`.

Comment: I don’t think I have access to the project I used this on, but I’m pretty sure it’s already in the view hierarchy by this stage so that might not work. If I have the same issue again I will give it a go though and update.

Comment: If it's a `UIButton` subclass then overriding `didMoveToSuperview()` lets you run code when the button is being added to the view hierarchy. That's the whole point of that method.

Comment: @HangarRash Yes exactly that was my point, the issue occurs after the view is already in the hierarchy. Honestly not able to check now but if it comes up again I will check and update.

Answer (score 3):

Changed UIButton type to Custom in IB worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

What did it for me was changing the button.tintColor in the highlighted state. This is swift 3, iOS 10

```
override public var isHighlighted: Bool {
    didSet {
        self.tintColor = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 255/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1.0)
    }
}
```

Or you can do the same in the interface builder

[Choose button state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbaPS.jpg)

[Choose button tint color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvhCi.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

From iOS 15 onward, UIButton has property **configuration**. You can set clear color to property **baseBackfroundColor** to remove background color of UIButton in selected mode.

```
var config = UIButton.Configuration.plain()
config.baseBackgroundColor = .clear
button.configuration = config
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this!!! This was exactly the fix I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Swift Version

```
extension UIButton {
    override public var highlighted: Bool {
        didSet {
            // clear background color when selected
            self.layer.backgroundColor = .None
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a UIButtonConfiguration, I had to make the following call:

```
btnCfg.baseBackgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Answer (score -1):

this will remove your UIButton background color when selected

```
@IBOutlet weak var submitButton: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
    submitButton = button
    submitButton.tintColor = .clear 
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Use...

```
    [myButton setAdjustsImageWhenHighlighted:FALSE];
```

Answer (score -2):

Not sure if this is the best way. But you could have an invisible button or view ontop of the actual button then recognize when the top button/view has been clicked.